# Middle verts snapping to other side of the model

Tags: mesh, vertices

I have encountered problem with middle edge loop of my model.
Some vertices of that edge loop are snapping to other side along Y axis when I'm trying to move them.

Model was previously sculpted a bit, and I was using mirror and multi resolution modifiers.

I first time noticed this problem when I was weight painting chin of my human, the weight paint was appearing also on the neck of the character. I also checked previous versions of my project, and weight paint has nothing to do with this issue.

I'm stuck on this, please help ;(
[image: bugged vertices location on human model]

On the image I selected whole edge loop and moved it along Y axis, ofc. there should be no gaps between vertices.

EDIT: After further checking it looks like whole mesh is weird, random parts are mirroring on X axis, even when I deleted all vertex groups, and have no active modifiers.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there were active X Mirror in edid mode, after dissabling it everything works just fine.

I never even imagined it could do weird stuff like that...